# How to run non static method from static inside single class and use dependency injection C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, oop, dependency-injection

I am trying to run non static method from static and use dependency Injection inside non static method. (I am trying to do this inside one class)

My code looks like this:

```
public class Tokens
{
    private IRefreshTokenRepository refreshTokenRepository;

    public Tokens(IRefreshTokenRepository refreshTokenRepository)
    {
        this.refreshTokenRepository = refreshTokenRepository;
    }

    // I understand that problem is there, but I should to write this
    //constructor because otherwise I can not use class variable in static method 
    public Tokens()
    {
    }


    public static async Task<string> GenerateJwt()
    {
        RefreshToken rf = new RefreshToken{...};

        Tokens t = new Tokens();
        t.StoreRefToken(rf);

        return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(...);
    }


    public async void StoreRefToken(RefreshToken reft)
    {
        this.refreshTokenRepository.InsertRefreshToken(reft);
        await refreshTokenRepository.SaveAsync();
    }


}
```

As you understand from code, when I wrote "Tokens t = new Tokens();" this code had used constructor without importing repository. What to do? Can I fix it inside single class?

Thank you

P.S. if question is silly I'm sorry

Comment: Why did you tag with java?

Comment: Because in Java dependency injection and "run non static method from static one" works in same way and I think Java developers could be answer. If I'm wrong please say why and I will remove tag.

Comment: Why using static to begin with? This appears to be an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). A [mcve] should help clarify the actual problem

Comment: Thank you Nkosi, I will definitely will read this article and question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Static and Dependency Injection do not play well together.

Keep `Tokens` as an instance class and abstract it

```
public interface ITokenService {
    Task<string> GenerateJwt();
}
```

so that it can be injected as a dependency.

derive `Tokens` from the abstraction

```
public class Tokens: ITokensService {
    private readonly IRefreshTokenRepository refreshTokenRepository;

    public Tokens(IRefreshTokenRepository refreshTokenRepository) {
        this.refreshTokenRepository = refreshTokenRepository;
    }

    public async Task<string> GenerateJwt() {
        RefreshToken rf = new RefreshToken{...};

        await StoreRefToken(rf);

        return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(...);
    }

    private async Task StoreRefToken(RefreshToken reft) {
        this.refreshTokenRepository.InsertRefreshToken(reft);
        await refreshTokenRepository.SaveAsync();
    }
}
```

Now you have access to the desired members where ever it is needed as a dependency

Comment: Thank you Nkosi. 1 question: If I made static method non static. Code will work anyway. Why I need to use Interface? Is it depend on business logic? Or it has some benefits in performance, security, etc.?